# specific link in CSS span definition

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I am currently writing a few html pages and some words need to have a style (bold, italics) and a link.
Is there a way to include specific hyperlink in the CSS so that if I define something like

```
span.myword {
     something that will link to a specific url
}
```

so that I can write something like 
    "[div] blah blah [span class="myword"]selected words[/span] blah blah[/div]"
and have a hyperlink included in the span class.

thank you in advance for your help

Comment: You can't include `HTML` element in `CSS`

Comment: no not possible you can use `span` wrapped in `<a>` tag

Answer (score 3):

You cannot make a span hyperlink strictly in CSS. However, you can do something like this:

```
a[href='http://www.google.com']
{
    //Apply styles to links to Google.
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gb774kt4/)

---

You could also just apply a class to an `<a>` element:

```
<div>
    blah blah
    <a href="#" class="myword">selected words</a>
    blah blah
</div>
```

Then style like this:

```
a.myword
{
    //Insert CSS here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to a jQuery solution, there is one.

Simply add the `.link` class to each link you want to make, define the custom key and URL in the javascript variable, and BAM! It uses the word inside of the span to pull the URL from the javascript object.:

---

### HTML:

```
<span class="link">Google</span>
<span class="link">Facebook</span>
<span class="link">StackOverflow</span>
```

---

### jQuery:

```
var links = {};
links["Google"] = "http://www.google.com";
links["Facebook"] = "http://www.facebook.com";
links["StackOverflow"] = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";

$(function(){
    $("span.link").click(function(){
       window.open(links[$(this).html()]); 
    });
});
```

---

### CSS:

```
span.link
{
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h4a5bfww/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way as I did.

```
<div class="entry-content">
<p>test test test test<a href="http://www.google.com">www.google.com</a> to learn more.</p>
</div>
```

CSS styles:

```
.entry-content p a {
color: #f47727;
}
```

You can style this with BOLD or italic as u need..

Comment: Thank you, but the aim is to try not to have to keep typing these long and repetitive URLs for these specific words and I am looking for a way to define a style that would somehow include all (each word refers to a specific URL.